# Pandas read_csv with multiple header permutations

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to use Pandas read_csv but I couldn't find the right options to have it read properly.

With the given CSV

```
DATETIME,A1_Pin,A2_Pin,A3_Pin,A4_Pin
2018/01/01 06:23:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:24:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:25:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:26:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:27:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:28:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:29:34.000,1,2,3,4
2018/01/01 06:30:34.000,1,2,3,4
DATETIME,A1_Pin,A3_Pin,A2_Pin
2018/01/01 06:31:34.000,1,3,2
```

The header can invariably change on me.

So writing a program to sum the values wouldn't necessarily work.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("datatable.csv")

print(data)

print(data.sum())
```

Result being

```
                  DATETIME  A1_Pin  A2_Pin  A3_Pin  A4_Pin
0  2018/01/01 06:23:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
1  2018/01/01 06:24:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
2  2018/01/01 06:25:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
3  2018/01/01 06:26:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
4  2018/01/01 06:27:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
5  2018/01/01 06:28:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
6  2018/01/01 06:29:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
7  2018/01/01 06:30:34.000       1       2       3     4.0
8                 DATETIME  A1_Pin  A3_Pin  A2_Pin     NaN
9  2018/01/01 06:31:34.000       1       2       3     NaN
DATETIME    2018/01/01 06:23:34.0002018/01/01 06:24:34.000...
A1_Pin                                        11111111A1_Pin1
A2_Pin                                        22222222A3_Pin2
A3_Pin                                        33333333A2_Pin3
A4_Pin                                                     32
dtype: object
```

Comment: What you have is a not well-formed CSV file and cannot be read with read_csv. If the first column name is always DATETIME, you can split the file into several files and read each of them independently.

Comment: Ya definitely not a traditional style CSV, I can understand the reason for this because if you removed or add a sensor it can change how many data points you log.